# Android application always at 1280x720 pixels while display is 1080p, why?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Application is running on Android 4.4 set-top box device connected to monitor/TV by HDMI. Device can output 480p 720p 1080p and 4K resolution on HDMI output, but my application is always rendered to 1280x720 and up-scaled to HDMI resolution.

Can my application always render to 4K resolution and downscale to HDMI resolution ?

I use this code to check for resolution:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getRealMetrics(metrics);
    log("Screen resolution: " + metrics.widthPixels + "x" + metrics.heightPixels);
    display.getSize(size);
    log("Current resolution: " + size.x + "x" + size.y);
    display.getRealSize(size);
    log("Real resolution: " + size.x + "x" + size.y);
```

And output is always 1280x720